# How to intercept every touch action before the view's click listener handles it?

Tags: android

So, My original problem is that I have started working on a huge android application which has too many activities and layouts. It is totally undocumented/commented and I have to deliver results in days. 
     So, I want to match, the elements in layouts ->> to the code, so that  I can understand the code faster.

If somehow I can define a global touch listener that can intercept every touch action and Log the associated view and it's parent layout, and after that hand the control over to the associated click listener.

Am I on the right path? is there any best practice in such scenarios?

Comment: Why don't you use Android development tools instead? Like View hirarchy viewer, the debugger...

Comment: thanks, actually I was looking for a better tools and solutions, can you point me to the right set of tools and documentation?

Comment: What I'm referring to are all part of the Android SDK tools, just dig in.

Comment: ok, how can the standard debugger help in my problem?

Comment: Too many ways, but a simple example is to put breakpoints on methods so you can see what is called when you press this or that.